# CakePHP First Successful Bake???, css doesn't seem to work

Tags: cakephp

I am a total newbie to programming so pls be patient with me if my question might sound dumb to you.

I am trying to learn the cakephp framework. I downloaded the latest stable version which is 1.3.8 and my server is WAMP.

I followed the tutorial on this link:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21Rt9HgITig

I was able to follow it and here's the result when opened the site on my localserver
[image: screen shot]

I don't know why the css doesn't weem to work when I think I successfuly baked it.

I think it sould have some color green background.

Pls help...

Comment: My guess is your `DocumentRoot` is not properly set to `webroot`. Or the paths in your configuration are wrong. Post your projects conf.

Comment: open up the source HTML and click on the CSS link. If cake gives you a 404 page, then your rewrites have not been set up properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [enable mod-rewrite](http://scriptperfect.com/2009/09/mod_rewrite-tutorial-for-wamp-modrewrite-mod-rewrite/).

Comment: Oh man it worked!!! Could you tell me about this mod-rewrite. I am completeley new to this.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that your mod-rewrite isn't working and pointing to correct file.

1. Confirm that your CSS is 404.
2. [Enable mod-rewrite](http://scriptperfect.com/2009/09/mod_rewrite-tutorial-for-wamp-modrewrite-mod-rewrite/) just like @tyler said.
3. Check if it worked.
4. Still hasn't work? There is a possibility that you might need [some changes](http://www.chriscassell.net/log/2006/07/27/how_to_install_.html) to do to your .htaccess, if your app is on an alias directory.